# Get form validation errors in Symfony 2.7 as a string

Tags: php, validation, symfony, error-handling

I'm getting a few form errors but i'm struggling to understand what the errors are, hence why the form is invalid. I'm using Symfony 2.7 and getting the errors using;

```
$errors = $form->getErrors(true, true);
```

I'd like them as a string so I can pass them to our logging application, however these are currently coming through as `<empty>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `(string)$form->getErrors()`, otherwise if you don't cast it to a string, it will be a long frightening array which may make no sense at first glance.

If you want to know the total number of errors that have occurred, use this,

`$form->count($form->getErrors())`

Answer (score -1):

maybe try

```
$form->getErrorsAsString()
```

When having trouble to retrieve errors from a form (mostly when several forms are nested), I use these 2 custom utils functions :

```
public function getErrorMessagesFromUnbubblingForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form)
{
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $template = $error->getMessageTemplate();
        $parameters = $error->getMessageParameters();

        foreach ($parameters as $var => $value) {
            $template = str_replace($var, $value, $template);
        }

        $errors[$key] = $template;
    }
    if ($form->count()) {
        foreach ($form as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessagesFromUnbubblingForm($child);
            }
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}

public function getFlatErrorMessagesFromUnbubblingForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form)
{
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
        $template = $error->getMessageTemplate();
        $parameters = $error->getMessageParameters();

        foreach ($parameters as $var => $value) {
            $template = str_replace($var, $value, $template);
        }

        $errors[] = $template;
    }
    if ($form->count()) {
        foreach ($form as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                $errors = $this->getFlatErrorMessagesFromUnbubblingForm($child);
            }
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: $form->getErrorsAsString() is deprecated isn't it?

Comment: right, deprecated since 2.5, removed in 3.0. according to doc, Use getErrors() instead and cast the result to a string. My bad i'm using 2.3